# How to perform the lfsr scrambling used in PCIe for 2 byte input?

Tags: lfsr, scrambling

In [PCIe](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwji5trIgu_jAhUc7HMBHR9UCeoQFjAAegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FPCI_Express&usg=AOvVaw2_ej78eSaujRl2QJQfq9BZ) Gen 3 on-wards there is [128b/130b encoding](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwir9afIge_jAhVI7XMBHZzNCD0QFjABegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%3Ftitle%3D128b%2F130b%26redirect%3Dno&usg=AOvVaw2bUCKpPRMBdDW7rNC8TA-0) used which scrambles incoming bit using a [LFSR](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwixoe7Zge_jAhVVjeYKHWxbD1QQFjACegQIDxAG&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLinear-feedback_shift_register&usg=AOvVaw3gjOtkrVpucPWoW1k9x0v3) with polynomial: $$G(X) = X^{23} + X^ {21} + X^{16} + X^{8} + X^5 + X^2 + 1.$$ Is there any way to perform required scrambling on 2 bit in one clock using parallel scramblers, where output of incoming msb will be dependent on lsb's output.

Comment: I don't think so. If you were able to, you can divide and conquer attack on a single LFSR, if I've understood correctly.

Comment: How can we decimate the given polynomial for getting odd and even sequence out of the sequence generated by this LFSR polynomial G(X)=X23+X21+X16+X8+X5+X2+1. I need two new LFSR which will follow only the odd sequence and even sequence of that whole sequence.

Comment: Please note that the PCIe uses LFSR not for security, but to reduce excessive di/dt.

Comment: @forest what is di/dt

Comment: @kodlu Interference in electronics. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/341319/177824.

Comment: Bursts of sequential 1s and 0s can cause sudden changes in power consumption, and can cause electromagnetic interference in a high-speed bus. Using an LFSR as a stream cipher makes it so that any data going over a bus appears random. DDR3/4 does it, high-speed USB does it, PCIe does it, etc. It ensures that the electronic stress and EMI is independent of the kind of data that is being sent.

Comment: @forest, thanks that's very informative.

Answer (score 2):

The online magma calculator

http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/

tells me this LFSR corresponds to a primitive polynomial since $$G(X) = X^{23} + X^ {21} + X^{16} + X^{8} + X^5 + X^2 + 1$$
is primitive.

Thus, some phase of the output sequence is given by $$tr(\alpha^t)$$ where $tr:GF(2^{23})\rightarrow GF(2)$ is the trace map and $\alpha \in GF(2^{23})$ is primitive.

The minimal polynomial of $\alpha^2$ is also $G(X)$ and it is the polynomial generating the decimation by 2 (the minimal polynomial of $\alpha^2.$ But this is the same polynomial since an element and its square are conjugates. This is because
$$
G(X)=\prod_{i=1}^{23} (X-\alpha^{2^{i-1}}),
$$
from standard finite field results.

The decimation by 2 is $s(t+2^{22})$ if $s(t)$ is the original sequence in its characteristic phase, i.e., the phase that satisfies $$s(2t)=s(t)$$
for all $t \pmod{2^{23}-1}.$

Comment: could you add the two polynomials?